# Different result using docker-compose vs docker run

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

I am setting up a generic common database that I can link to with other containers. I am encountering different results when using `docker-compose` and `docker run`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root-secret
        MYSQL_USER: dbuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: my-secret
    volumes:
        - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
        - mysql:db
    ports:
        - 8088:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root-secret
        MYSQL_USER: dbuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: my-secret
```

The docker commands that I am running are:

```
docker run -d -P --name mysql -v conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v data:/var/lib/mysql \
    -v logs:/var/log/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-secret \
    -e MYSQL_USER=dbuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-secret -p 3306:3306 mariadb:10.1
docker run -d --name pma --link mysql:db  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-secret \
    -e MYSQL_USER=dbuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-secret -p 8088:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

When using `docker-compose up -d`, everything works properly and my host's data directory is filled with the database files. In addition, phpmyadmin is able to connect to the database container without issue.

When using the docker commands the host's data directory stays empty and the data is stored within the container. phpmyadmin gives me "access denied" when attempting to login as well.

Can anyone tell me why the data volume mounts properly and phpmyadmin is able to comunicate when using docker-compose but not with docker?

Comment: Maybe just a typo in how you map the volumes. In the docker-compose file you use "./data:.." and in the docker run command you use "data:.." . So it is dependent on where you run the docker run command / where your docker-compose.yml file is located. For docker-compose.yml all the paths are relative to where the file is.

Comment: Both commands are executed within the same directory. When I attempt to use ./data in the docker command it gives me an error that the path is not valid due to the leading dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following commands:

```
docker run -d -P --name mysql \
  -v $(pwd)/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
  -v $(pwd)/data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -v $(pwd)/logs:/var/log/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-secret \
  -e MYSQL_USER=dbuser \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-secret \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  mariadb:10.1 

docker run -d --name pma \
  --link mysql:db  \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-secret \
  -e MYSQL_USER=dbuser \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-secret \
  -p 8088:80 \
  phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

**Reason**

You're not mounting the volumes right. In the `docker-compose.yml` file you're specifying paths, relative to the directory where the file resides

```
volumes:
    - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
```

In the `docker run` command, however, you're not using relative paths

```
-v conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v data:/var/lib/mysql -v logs:/var/log/mysql
```

In addition, `docker run` requires that you specify absolute paths to the local directories you want to mount inside the container.
So instead using a syntax similar to `docker-compose.yml`, you have to use something like `pwd` to get the absolute path, or write your paths by hand.

```
-v /path/to/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
-v /path/to/data:/var/lib/mysql \
-v path/to/logs:/var/log/mysql \
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the difference is in how you specify the volume paths. But so far nobody has explained why, even though you specified the volumes "incorrectly" in `docker run`, Docker accepted them without error and kept going, or why you saw the behavior you saw.

### docker-compose

In docker-compose.yml, you used this:

```
volumes:
  - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
  - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
  - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
```

In this case you are taking local relative paths, with a leading `./`, and mounting inside the container using absolute paths. This works just fine.

### docker run

In your `docker run` commands, you used this:

```
-v conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v data:/var/lib/mysql -v logs:/var/log/mysql
```

It's obvious that you intended this to mean "use the relative path." As you already mentioned, if you specify a relative path with a leading `./` here, you will get an error, i.e. you cannot do this:

```
-v ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v ./data:/var/lib/mysql -v ./logs:/var/log/mysql
```

### What happened

You note that when you run via docker-compose it works as you expect: the host mounted volumes are used. But when you run via `docker run`, the data is kept inside the container instead, and the host mounted directories are not used. Why?

The reason is that the `-v` syntax you used *does* have a valid purpose, it's just not the one you thought. The way you specified it, you created *named* Docker volumes. The leading part before the colon follows these rules:

1. If a leading `./` is seen, this is a relative directory: **Error**
2. If a leading `/` is seen, this is an absolute path. Mount volume into container.
3. If you give something like `foo/bar` this is assumed to be a relative path. **Error**
4. Finally, if you specify `word:/some/path`, then `word` is taken to be a name. A Docker volume is created with the name `word`, and mounted in the container at `/some/path`.

So when using `docker run`, you created volumes. These were being used inside the container. Volumes were in use, just not host-mounted volumes.

### Unable to connect error

I see nothing wrong with your setup in terms of networking. My best guess about your connection error is that in the `docker run` scenario, your databases were not being set up correctly, therefore phpmyadmin was not able to use mysql. If you correct the volume problem and phpmyadmin continues to have issues, update your question with any specific errors you are getting, and leave a comment on my answer so I can look again.

### References

[Docker run reference (VOLUME)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems)

> -v, --volume=[host-src:]container-dest[:]: Bind mount a volume.
>   The comma-delimited options are [rw|ro], [z|Z],
>   [[r]shared|[r]slave|[r]private], and [nocopy].
>   The 'host-src' is an absolute path or a name value.
>
> A name value must start with an alphanumeric character, followed by a-z0-9, _ (underscore), . (period) or - (hyphen). An absolute path starts with a / (forward slash).

[Manage data in containers (Removing volumes)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#removing-volumes)

> A Docker data volume persists after a container is deleted. You can create named or anonymous volumes. Named volumes have a specific source form outside the container, for example `awesome:/bar`. Anonymous volumes have no specific source.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works for me with both docker-compose and your docker run lines. Note that you don't need the `-P` flag, the docs say that this publishes all exposed ports to random ports -- not probably what you are intending, since you are specifying a `-p` flag also.

```
 -P, --publish-all                 Publish all exposed ports to random ports
```